# Average length of commands in zsh_history

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I can see that so far, I've executed 2689 commands:

```
❯ wc -l < $HISTFILE
2689
```

My `$HISTFILE` points to `zsh_history` that stores commands in this format:

```
❯ tail -n 5 $HISTFILE
: 1576891734:0;clear
: 1576891735:0;neofetch
: 1576891738:0;ls -lA
: 1576891756:0;ls -ld
: 1576891764:0;tail -n 5 $HISTFILE
```

Now I'm trying to find out the average length of all the commands in this file, how can I do that?

Comment: The `wc` command does not give you the total amount of command in your history. Just the total amount of lines. It is possible that you have multi-line commands listed in the history.

Comment: @kvantour Is [this](https://superuser.com/a/1511806/735590) the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZSH has multiple history-file formats such as the so-called *extended history format*, which is enabled by the [`EXTENDED_HISTORY` shell option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#History). On top of that, multi-line commands are stored in a multi-line format. So processing the history-file directly is not really the way forward as it depends on some zsh hooks and other features from zsh.

If you make use of the `EXTENDED_HISTORY` your format in your `$HISTFILE` looks like:

```
: <beginning time>:<elapsed seconds>;<command>
```

where the beginning time is presented in unix epoch and the elapsed seconds in seconds. So the following regex will solve find this part that is not part of the command:

```
^: [0-9]+:[0-9]+;
```

So the quick way with awk would be like this:

```
awk '{n+=sub(/^: [0-9]+:[0-9]+;/,"");l+=length}END{(l+NR-n)/n}' "$HISTFILE"
```

**How does this work:**

1. We always substitute the following history pattern away. If such substitution happened, the command `sub` will return `1` and it indicates we have a new command. The command count is tracked with `n`.
2. We always count the length of the command after the substitution and store the total length of all commands in the variable `l`.
3. At the `END` we need to correct for the missing newlines for multi-line commands, so we need to add `NR-n` newline characters to `l`

**caveats:**

There are still problems with multi-line commands. When a multi-line command is written, it always ends with a <backslash> character. This is not really part of the command, so we would have to compensate for it.

```
awk '/^: [0-9]+:[0-9]+;/ && (mc==0){n++;sub(/^: [0-9]+:[0-9]+;/,"")}
     /[\\]$/ { mc=1 }
     !/[\\]$/ { mc=0 }
     { sub(/[\\]$/,""); l+=length }
     END{(l+NR-n)/n}' "$HISTFILE"
```

I believe that this will do everything correct. But I also think we can still break it with a set of unique commands.

**OLD ANSWER:**

Another way you could get a result is by processing the command `fc -l 1 -1` which essentially prints the command history in a single line with a number in front. Example:

```
 % fc -l 1 -1 | tail      
 3005  man zshall
 3006  fc -R ~/.zhistory
 3007  fc -P
 3008  cat ~/.zhistory
 3009  fc -l 1 -1
 3010  fc -l 1 -1 | more
 3011  fc -l 1 -1 | awk 'END{print NR}'
 3012  fc -l 1 -1 | head
 3013  head ~/.zhistory
 3014  head ~/.zhistory | tail
```

**Remark:** this does not start counting from 1 (don't ask me why).

So the following commands might help you out:

```
# print total number of commands
$ fc -l 1 -1 | awk 'END{print NR}'
# print basic average length of commands
$ fc -l 1 -1 | awk '{sub(/^[[:blank:]]*[0-9]+[[:blank:]]*/,""); l+=length}END{print length/NR}'
```

You should be aware, however, that this will not give a correct answer when you type a multi-line command. Example

```
$ for i in 1; do
for> echo $i
for> done
1
2
$ fc -l -1
3020  for i in 1; do\necho $i\ndone
```

As you see, the new-line characters are replaced by `\n`. So the <newline>-character will be counted as 2 characters. We could compensate for that by using awk and searching for this combination. The problem exists, however, when you type a commands like these:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "foo"
$ for i in 1; do
for> printf "%d\n" "$i"
for> done
```

Here, the `\n` becomes a part of the command and should not be compensated.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following in case your any of the command or code itself having `;` then also it will NOT fail.

```
awk 'match($0,/[^;]*;/){ 
  sum+=length(substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH))
  fnr=FNR
}
END{
  print sum/fnr
}
' "$HISTFILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
❯ sed 's/.*;//' $HISTFILE | awk '{sum+=length}END{print sum/NR}'
```

Now let's see how it works.

First, we need to get rid of everything before `;` in the `.zsh_history` file so that we only have the commands. This can be achieved by `sed`:

```
❯ sed 's/.*;//' $HISTFILE
```

The `sed` command above matches *everything* (`.*`) before the *semicolon* (`;`) and replaces it with nothing, thus removing it.

Now if we pipe the output of this command into `awk`, we can find the length of each line, like this:

```
❯ sed 's/.*;//' $HISTFILE | awk '{print length}'
```

So now we have length of each line, all there's left to do is average them. Which can be done by summing the length of each line (`sum+=length`) and then dividing it by the number of lines (`NR`).

As pointed out by [@bishop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59432942/average-length-of-commands-in-zsh-history#comment105051589_59432943), there's no need for the `sed` command, because `awk` can manipulate the text as well. The command can thus be rewritten as follows:

```
awk -F ';' '{ sum+=length($2) } END { print sum/NR }' $HISTFILE
```

Comment: No need for `sed`, because `awk` can manipulate the text as well:
`awk -F ';' '{ sum+=length($2) } END { print sum/NR }' $HISTFILE`

Comment: You're welcome. You may also want to guard against the case where NR=0, though the error message that's spit out ("division by zero") is probably self-explanatory.

Comment: This will fail in case your commands in history have `;` could you please try my code once that will take care of this edge case.

Comment: @bishop, IMHO in some of the awks END may not print last line's value or FNR value so I created a variable in my solution to take care of this edge case, thought to share with you.

Comment: This will fail with multiline commands, commands containing the semicolumn character (`;`) like `while :; do ... done` and various other cases.